# Readings on Tensors, Tensor Algebra and Tensor Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation, tensors, kronecker-product, tensor-decomposition

I have just started my Masters Degree in Mathematics and I will be focussing on Tensors (Viewed as Multidimensional Arrays) and Tensor decompositions.

My professor is by no means an expert on Tensors so he has asked me to do some reading on Tensors focusing on algebra and decomposition. The goal is to be able to explain what I've learnt to him. Since he isn't an expert he can't recommend me much reading. So can you guys recommend good textbooks and articles.

I should also mention that one of my main starting objectives are to read and understand the paper "Tensor-Train Decomposition" by Ivan Oseledets (https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/090752286).

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend Algebra by Serge Lang, the 16th chapter. But you don't have to read the whole 15 chapter to understand tensors. At least you should read about multilinear algebra firstly. Also you can look at Brown's A second Course in Linear Algebra.